# Moving values from a row to the next tab without keeping formatting in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to move a row to the next tab once "Live" has been selected from a drop down menu. I just want the values and for the formatting to be disregarded.

I have had this working in the past on edit, but a recently it has decided that it it wont work unless i have a button to press on the sheet and it has also started dragging through all the data validation and conditional formatting with it. I haven't changed anything in the script, and don't think any of my colleagues have either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function Projects(e) {
  // moves whole row when "Live" is selected from drop down menu
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Projects";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 8;
  var valueToWatch = "Live";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Status Tracker";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `Range#getValues` with `setValues` or `Sheet#appendRow` if you want explicitly only values (e.g. formulas to static values, no formatting transfer, no validation transfer, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Delete the trigger and re-install it.
2. Instead of using [`moveTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget), which includes formatting, use [`copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options) and include the `contentsOnly` option.

The modified code below should work for you. Note that I've also made some changes so that it's taking full advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) being passed to it.

```
function Projects(e) {
  // moves whole row when "Live" is selected from drop down menu
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Projects";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 8;
  var valueToWatch = "Live";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Status Tracker";

  var ss = e.source; // use the event object to get the spreadsheet
  var range = e.range; // use the event object to get the edited cell
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet(); // use the event object to the get the sheet
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true});
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
```

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for your suggestions. After a bit of fiddling it all seems to be working again.